# mongo java driver returning stale data from primary

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using `mongo version 2.4.5` and `mongo-java-driver version 2.12.4`. I have a primary node and a replica.

Now i run a code which does following:

```
SAVE 1 - inserts a new document with default write concern

...waits for some time

READ 1 - reads the document with read preference as primary

...modifies it

SAVE 2 - Save the modified doc with default write concern

READ 2 - reads back the saved doc immediately with read preference as primary
```

In the last read operation, which is done immediately after the save, i see that the stale data is returned in some cases(that is modifications are not reflecting). However, in some cases modifications do reflect.

Question - 
If i am writing to mongo with default write concern(which is acknowledged) and then reading back with preference primary, then isn't consistency guaranteed?

More Details:

1. Application is connecting to a replica set with 1 primary and 1 secondary host.
2. I tried overriding the default write concern with following: ACKNOWLEDGED, JOURNALED, RELPICA_ACKNOWLEDGED
   In all the cases, read preference was PRIMARY. Still this issue was observed.

   private DBCollection customers = myDB.getCollection("customers");

   WriteResult wr = customers.save(customer,concern);

   if (wr.getN() > 0) {

   ans = true;

   } else
     ans = false;

   } catch (Exception e) {

   ans = false;

   e.printStackTrace();

   }

Comment: We're going to need more details here.  Is your application connecting to a standalone server, a replica set, or a sharded cluster?  Is your application constructing a MongoClient or a Mongo instance?  If the latter, is your application changing the default write concern to ACKNOWLEDGED, as Mongo defaults to UNACKNOWLEDGED?

Comment: @jyemin Thanks for taking interest ing this Qs. I have added more details in the Qs.